# Checking if blast out for multiple files in a folder automatically

Tags: blast

I have done multiple small blast runs. Now I want to check automatically if all files got completed properly with correct ending.

For example, if I check the ending of a particular file I see:

```
n85567:Mel_Sanger mitras$ tail /Volumes/ForBlastLactose/output/S5_1FIL_ab.out 

 Database: SILVA_119_SSURef_tax_silva
    Posted date:  Jan 6, 2015  11:55 AM
  Number of letters in database: 2,241,843,227
  Number of sequences in database:  1,583,830

Matrix: blastn matrix 1 -2
Gap Penalties: Existence: 0, Extension: 2.5
```

So if finished properly the file will have the ending line `Gap Penalties: Existence: 0, Extension: 2.5`

So now my question is how can I right a script to check all files in a folder for this particular ending and report back with the name of the files if there is mismatch in ending.

I was trying something like:

```
 if [[for f in *.out; tail -1 ${f} == "Gap Penalties: Existence: 0, Extension: 2.5"; then echo "All files are fine"; else echo "Error file:"$f; fi
```

but being a novice in scripting I am obviously nor getting it right.

Can anybody please help me to do it. 
Thanks a lot,
Mitra

Comment: `tail -1` will give you the last line only which could be compared to the expected result. Most questions here are about DOS/Windows batch file scripting. Also, you might want to write the right script.

Comment: Yes thats I want help for... in writing a right script that can check the end of all files using tail. and let me know if any didn't get the goos ending. Thanks, Mitra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not generally expect to come to stackoverflow.com and expect people to write code for you. I am sure you can take it from here.

```
$ cat endcheck
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.txt;
do
    s=$(tail -1 $i)
    if [ "$s" != "Gap Penalties: Existence: 0, Extension: 2.5" ]
    then
        echo File $i does not have the correct ending.
    fi
done

pwatson@tmc002 ~/y
$ ./endcheck
File t1.txt does not have the correct ending.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul for the help. Yes I know and I was not really expecting a complete code from somebody... but as a novice I was expecting to get help in my try...as you can see above what I tried before.. I was struggling to get the right use pattern of for and if together. Thanks for your help. Cheers Mitra.

Comment: If this works for you, please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi I am not sure how to mark it as answered. I clicked on your answer as helpful, but as I am new user its not showing.

Comment: @user3042163 - To the left of the answer there is an up triangle, down triangle, and a check mark. Please try selecting the check mark.

Comment: I tried the same but it says once I score 15 reputaion then only my vote will be publicly displayed.